# Comparing mac addresses in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, mac-address

I was able to get the mac address of the router; But when I compare it it shows nothing. Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    getMacId();
    // myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 5000);
    display.setText(" Mac Address of current connected wifi is");
    // MacText.setText(getMacId());
    String MacID = getMacId(); 
    box.setText(MacID);

    String rajaWing = "f4:7f:35:5f:43:50" ;
    String usmanWing = "f4:7f:35:5f:43:a0"; 
    String shahzadWing = "00:3a:98:88:91:a0";
    //sets location name
    if (getMacId() == "usmanWing") {
        MacText.setText("Usman's Wing");
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String is an Object.

In order to compare its value, not its memory address, use

String.equals(String);

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Change `getMacId() == "usmanWing"` to `getMacId().equals("usmanWing")`

Since you are comparing two Strings so you should use `"YOUR_STRING".equals("COMPARE_STRING")` method.